# Why isn't 'emacs the same as 'emacs here?

Tags: emacs, quote

This first one should return t but isn't doing so, while the other is returning t.
They should be the same.

```
(defvar list '((binds . 'emacs)))
(eq (cdr (assoc 'binds list)) 'emacs) ;; returns nil
```

```
(eq 'emacs 'emacs) ;; returns t
```

```
(type-of 'emacs) ;; returns symbol
(type-of (cdr (assoc 'binds list))) ;; Returns cons
```

What is going on here?

Comment: In fact they *shouldn't* be the same -- and indeed they are not.  You would be better to phrase such a question  as "I thought that they would be the same, but they are not.  Why is that?"

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: "hahahahahahha" is different from hahahahahahha. `(eq ''emacs 'emacs)` is `nil`, that's all. The first arg of `eq` evaluates to the list `(quote emacs)`; the second arg evaluates to the symbol `emacs` - two different animals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

```
(equal (cdr (assoc 'binds list)) ;; (quote emacs)
       (quote (quote emacs))
```

i.e. the `cdr` part returns `'emacs` while `'emacs` returns just the symbol itself without the quote.

Comment: Still returns nil.

Comment: I've fixed that.  The two are `equal` but not `eq`, as they are independent lists.